# previsualización de la siguiente/anterior imagen css jquery bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Quisiera previsualizar la siguiente y anterior foto en un carousel de boostrap.
Esta es la idea:

https://codepen.io/Mrrowlie/pen/bGbLOdv

Tengo lo siguiente: (silo ejecutan veran lo que tengo)

Entonces simplemente necesito previsualizar las imagenes anterior y posterior abajo de las flechas.

Espero puedan ayudar, gracias.

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="es">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
      </head>
      <body>
        <style>
             .w-80{
                 width: 80% !important;
             }
        </style>

    <div class="container my-5 " >
        
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://stylelovely.com/wp-content/uploads/ropa-para-ninos-primavera-2018-el-corte-ingles-vestido-flores.jpg" class="d-block w-80 mx-auto" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://stylelovely.com/wp-content/uploads/ropa-para-ninos-primavera-2018-el-corte-ingles-vestido-flores.jpg" class="d-block w-80 mx-auto" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://stylelovely.com/wp-content/uploads/ropa-para-ninos-primavera-2018-el-corte-ingles-vestido-flores.jpg" class="d-block w-80 mx-auto" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class=" mr-5" style="font-size:4rem; color:black;"> <- </i>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="  ml-5" style="font-size:4rem; color:black;">-></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste guiarte con el código que justamente está en el pen que agregaste como referencia?

Comment: Si, las estructuras de código en ambos ejemplos es muy diferente. A los sumo robo algún que otro estilo. no mas que eso.

Comment: @TomasBoo pues si quieres que funcione, debes "robar" el script JS que es el que hace toda la magia en el snnipet que nos enseñas

Comment: Hasta donde sé Bootstrap no cuenta con un carrusel así y deberás hacerlo tu mismo.

Comment: Bootstrap tiene carousel. No era el que necesitaba. Ya lo hice igualmente.